# Unit of Measurement for product In Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

In my Magento website I want to show some products:

- some as per piece
- some as per kg
- some as per packet

How can I show the prices of products like: `$50 /kg, $50 /packet, $50 /pieces` in the frontend?

Comment: Create a attribute and call it in front-end

Comment: Done , thanks alot.